# Get value on perl script from another perl script

Tags: linux, script, perl

I have two perl scripts. The first perl script call another perl script, and then I want to get the result from the other script and use it in the first script to made a condition.
I use:

system("perlscript2.pl");

for execute the second script for the first one, but I don't know how to catch the value returned.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks for this, so:

```
my $output_from_first_script = `perlscript2.pl 2>&1`
```

The 2>&1 is to catch output sent to STDERR instead of STDOUT (the backticks only catch STDOUT).